# How to give different access to different type of user for login in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I am creating an application on Android in which I am using Firebase as a database. I have three different kinds of users in that which are operators, managers, administrators to each one I want to give different kinds of access to every one of them like operator, manager can view and add data whereas admin can add/delete/view data. I tried using email & auth tab in Firebase but it doesn't allow me to set the type of user on it. I just require help on the aspect on how do I have different login types for different users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase Authentication (as its name implies) just authenticates the user: it ensures the user is who they say they are. It has no ability to set a specific user type.

To restrict access for user based on their identity requires that you write rules for your database. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

The model you're describing is known as role-based security ad has been covered before. After reading the documentation, I recommend searching for more information on that.