# How to distinguish different types of users in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have three types of users in my app. I want to be able to distinguish between users at the time of the login, so I can start their respective activities in Android. 
I am using firebase for backend services. Please suggest a way of doing this in an easy way.

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907879/how-to-give-different-access-to-different-type-of-user-for-login-in-firebase

Comment: that question is about access of database, i am having trouble distinguishing my users

Comment: what do you mean by different types of users ? can you give some e.g

Comment: for example in a system there can be admin and normal users... in my app there are three like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user create his account in your app, add an entity like rank, ask him to select his rank.

and save this rank in your firebase database against his id. when user will login, you check it's rank and show activities according to his rank, Got it ?

Comment: please share some sample code if you could... It would be very much appriciated

Comment: Sir, its so simple, when user signup you ask him for his name, email etc. at the same time show him three radio button, like userType (i) experience (ii) normal (iii) low. user will select one of them. save his type or rank in dataBase. when User will login, you fetch all his data including his type or rank. now you can show him some activities according to his type or rank.

Comment: Thank you, you saved the day